# Why calling a method outside a Ruby class throws NoMethod error and how to fix it?

Tags: ruby

I have some class with a few methods inside it:

```
class Function
    def triangular_number(n)
        @result = 0
        for i in 1..n
        @result += i
        end
        @result
    end
    def factorial(n)
        @result = 1
        for i in 2..n
        @result *= i
        end
        @result
    end
    ...
end
```

When I try to call after the code of the class in the same file `puts Function.triangular_number(4)`, it throws `undefined method 'triangular_number' for Factorial:Class (NoMethodError)`. I guess it is because methods are not visible by default. If this assumption is true, then how to make methods visible. If this assumption is false, how to fix the error anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methods are *instance methods*, so you have to create an instance first, e.g.:

```
f = Function.new
f.factorial(4)
```

In order to call the method directly on the class, you have to define them as *class methods*:

```
class Function
  def self.triangular_number(n)
    # ...
  end

  def self.factorial(n)
    # ...
  end
end
```

And instead of instance variables, you should use local variables for proper encapsulation, i.e.

```
def self.factorial(n)
  result = 1
  for i in 2..n
    result *= i
  end
  result
end
```

or a little more idiomatic via [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#reduce-method):

```
def factorial(n)
  (2..n).reduce(1, :*)
end
```

---

Another option is define them in a module via [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#module_function-method):

```
module Function
  def triangular_number(n)
    # ...
  end
  module_function :triangular_number

  def factorial(n)
    # ...
  end
  module_function :factorial
end
```

These can be called on the module itself:

```
Function.factorial(4)
```

Or be included into another class: (where they become private instance methods)

```
class Calculator
  include Function

  def do_something
    factorial(4)
  end
end
```